# Do you see an issue with this schematic for programming a STM32WB30CE on SWD?

Tags: stm32, swd

My problem is that I have "no STM32 target found" message when I try to connect to a board by SWD through a ST-Link/v2 (no board identified).

On an oscilloscope, when we look at the SWDIO pin, a little event happens when initializing connection on stm32cubeprogrammer but then nothing.

Can it be a problem with the design itself? Just by the schematics, do you see a problem? It's an [SRM32WB30CE](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32wb30ce.pdf).

I have a custom board with these connections for SWD programming:

[image]

These pins are connected like this on the MCU:

[image]

Do you see a problem in the schematic to program this MCU by SWD?

Here are the VDD parts in case the problem is there:

[image]

Comment: Is your debugger connected to the reset pin or just SWDIO/SWCLK? I've had issues in the past with STM32s where they get "stuck" and need a physical reset for the debugger to attach.

Comment: @Brendan a reset button, present on an adaptator for the st-link/v2, is connected to the reset pin. The reset pin receives the signal from the button

Comment: That's not quite what I mean; the debugger has the capability to put the core into reset via SWD or, if that fails, via physical reset. Can you convert your STLink to a Jlink and use Jlink commander? I find that to be more helpful than the ST tools.